# Spawning children and exec - undefined behavior

Tags: c++, fork, exec

I've made a very simple program calling forking and calling another problem.While it does what I want to , a bug occurs and cout occurs double the times of for loop. Here is the code :
main.cpp

```
`#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>

using namespace std;

char *Strduplicate(const char *source) {
    char *dest = (char *) malloc(strlen(source) + 1); // +1 = '\0'
    if (dest == NULL)
        return NULL;
    strcpy(dest, source);
    return dest;
}

string Get_cwd(string word) {
    char cwd[256];
    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
    strcat(cwd,"/");
    strcat(cwd,word.c_str());
    string returnVal(cwd);
    return returnVal;
}

void Call_exec(const char *name,int value) {
    char *exec_array[3];
    exec_array[0] = Strduplicate(name);
    exec_array[1] = (char *)malloc(2);
    exec_array[1] = (char *)"-m";
    asprintf(&(exec_array[2]), "%d", value);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
        cout << exec_array[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    execv(exec_array[0],exec_array);
}

int main(int argc ,char **argv) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    /* Getting arguments */
    //........
    /* Spawning children */
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {
        int value = rand()%100 + 1;
        pid_t waiterpid = fork();
        if (waiterpid < 0)
            cout << "ERROR FORK" << endl;
        else if (!waiterpid) {
            string program_name = Get_cwd("child");
            Call_exec(program_name.c_str(),value);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
`
```

and the other process is child.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc ,char **argv) {
    cout << "Child #" << getpid() << " has started" << endl;
    int value;
    /* Getting arguments */
    if (argc != 3) {
        cerr << "ERROR : Wrong arguments" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        if (strncmp(argv[1],"-m",2) == 0)
            value = atoi(argv[2]);
    }
    cout << "Child has " << value << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

the output is

```
mypath/child -m 31 
mypath/child -m 23 
mypath/child -m 48 
mypath/child -m 23 
mypath/child -m 48 
alex@alex$ Child #13063 has started
Child #13062 has started
Child has 48
Child has 23
mypath/child -m 48 
Child #13064 has started
Child has 48
```

So what I misunderstand here?

Comment: half of this code is either UB or standard non-compliant (starting from header usage..) if you're learning C++., forget C. If it's  tutors requirements to not use _features_ of C++, comply but maybe  good time to consider  to look at alternatives and to keep it in mind.

Comment: e.g. including stdlib.h is UB, though you did that AFTER already including right header, cstdlib.  Including  string.h is wrong too.  `using namespace std` in _global_ scope may lead to possible UBs although not in this snippet.. just keep it in mind that you can use using in local scope or pull required names , like `using std::cin`. There is no STL anymore, well, STL is a separate library that might be available for historical reasons, if you have iostream, you're already using C++ template library (not STL). Do not use malloc\free\realloc in C++ code, use new and delete (and placement new).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's misunderstood here are the general principles of writing modern C++ code. There is no reason whatsoever to use these awful-looking C-style dynamic memory allocations. Everything that's done here can be done much cleaner, using containers, with the resulting code being at least three times smaller.

Oh, and `execv`'s parameter array must be terminated by a `NULL` pointer. It is not, so this results in undefined behavior. Most likely, the  `execv` system call fails, due to this garbage parameter - most likely with an `EFAULT` according to my perusal of its manual page.

Thusly, `execv()` actually returns in the child process. Since the shown code fails to check its return value: a child process, randomly, is going to continue executing upon returning from `execv()`, returning to `main()` in the child process, and continues with its own merry-go-round of the outer `for` loop, hence resulting in the duplicate output.

Comment: STL is not allowed and since I want dynamic exec I can't use execl either so that's why I ended up doing it this way.